# PowerApps- how to create a form where users can edit or delete rows that have been submitted

Tags: forms, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

**What I have:**
As of now, I have created a Form (editable) where the user can enter their Name, Number, and Birthday, then hit the submit button, and that data is then entered into a Data Table. This information is also stored into Google Sheets for which I have created a flow. (when the user hits "submit", trigger the data to be updated into the google sheet).

**What I need:** 
 I would like users to be able to mess with the submitted data in the app itself (add a row, delete a row when you click on it, edit the row's info, etc), so essentially my powerapp is a nice front end for the Google Sheet. Is it possible to mess with the data once it is entered into the data table?

Any help how to do this would be appreciated.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you started building Canvas app from scratch, so the screen has list below and "Add screen" on top. This way you have to introduce the Edit screen/operation & [save changes using PATCH command](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Write-and-append-to-an-Excel-file/td-p/131194).

There is another way: [Create an app automatically from your data in PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/ca-es/blog/create-an-app-automatically-from-your-data-in-powerapps/). This will give you the **Browse Screen**, **Detail Screen** & **Edit Screen** (aka New record screen) by default with all the Create, Read, Update, Delete (CRUD) operations right away using the Connection - Google sheet in your case.

> [image]

[Video tutorial for assistance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3za1oheYRs)